# Discord JS V13.6.0 issue when I try to create a role

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to add a mute role to a user in a slash commands but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```js
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('mute')
        .setDescription('Mute someone')
        .addUserOption(option => option.setName("member").setRequired(true).setDescription("Member to mute")),
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (interaction.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Admin")) {
            const membre = interaction.options.getUser("member");
            const guild=interaction.member.guild
            const role = await guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "MUTED");;
            membre.roles.add(role);
        }
        else {
            await interaction.reply({content: "**YOU DON'T HAVE THE PERMISSIONS !**", ephemeral: true });
        }
        
    },
};
```

Here is my error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\sunda\Downloads\chabibot-main\commands\mute.js:17:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sunda\Downloads\chabibot-main\index.js:29:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const membre = interaction.options.getUser('member'); // user
const membre = interaction.options.getMember('member'); // member
```

Role adding is only available on member not user.

[Docs](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#parsing-options)